# C Programming: Structs and typedefs for Graph with adjacency list

Tags: c, graph, adjacency-list

```
typedef struct GraphRep *Graph;
typedef int Vertex;

typedef struct _adjListNode {
Vertex         w;
int         weight;
struct _adjListNode *next;
} adjListNode;

typedef adjListNode* AdjList;
```

The header file I have has these features, my task is to create a adjacency list graph using this from scratch, so far i have these:

```
struct GraphRep{
int nV;                // number of vertices (also == to size of array)
struct AdjList* array; // array where each index is the vertex pointing to a 
                       // list of its adjacent nodes
};
```

First of all, I'm confused about how to properly call the adjacency list into the struct array, im not sure how to typedefs and structs work well.

This is also homework, I mainly want help around understanding what the code is doing how its linked.

Comment: What do you mean by "call the adjacency list into the struct array"?

Comment: If this is a homework you might consider approaching it according to the quite well-accepted compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: a better way to say it is i dont know how to properly call the struct for the adjacency list into the graph struct i made, because I need it inside there

Comment: Thatis using again exactly the unclear phrase. Please try to reword especially that part. Note that "calling" usually refers to using a function, not a data structure.

Comment: Do you know the concept of a "linked list"? If not read up on that topic and redo some practice assignments on it.

Comment: i don't know if this would sound clearer, but my main confusion is around the typedef and the pointer to it, (typedef adjListNode* AdjList;) does this mean if i just call AdjList,  i will be able to access all the struct values within?

Comment: i realised my compilation error is gone after i change it to AdjList array instead of struct AdjList* array, but i'm not sure what the problem was (why the error happened)?

Comment: I did not notice you mentioning a compilation error. But I see you have shown code and then deleted it again. Do show your own work, that is good. Also give all the details you have about the compiler error, especially quote it verbatim and somehow identify the line it is referring to, because line numbers probably do not help. For this it is important to make a [mcve].

Comment: I am sorry but I have to leave now. I will be back in some 10 hours. Meanwhile work on your question, probably someone else will also help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I realised I haven't researched before asking a question, I'll thank your advice from the answer and try to go through it before asking when I specifically know the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offering help according to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Hint 1)
Make sure that you are confortable with the concept of "linked lists", especially "single linked lists". It is a very important tool for this assignment.
If necessary do a tutorial on that topic first, or read up in your class material and redo some of the practice assignments on that.
Then look for two examples of linked lists in the data structures you have shown.

Hint 2)
The graph is going to be represented with one list of nodes and for each of them a list of adjacancies. Look those terms up, too.
Note that each of those lists is of unknown length, which changes which each new graph. So arrays with fixed lengths do not help. For each node you need to be able to name any number of adjacant other nodes. And you need to be able to work with any number of nodes.

Hint 3)
Put 1) and 2) together. How can 2) be solved by using the tools from 1)?